# What is the equivalent of 'this.state' with the new react useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am practicing the new React hooks and I was wondering if anyone figured out what the equivalent is of console.log(this.state) in terms of the useState hook in a function component.

Regards!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--there isn't an "equivalent"; the first value in the array returned from `useState` is the current state of that `useState` hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make sense. What I mean is: In a class based component I can console.log(this.state) and it returned me all the objects, arrays, strings etc. whats in the entire state of the page. In this function component I only found a way to specifically select a certain state. Is there not a equivalent way to get the entire state of the hook? As you said, in an array for example. Cause if I use console.log(useState) I just get the function. If I use useState() it's giving me an error, obviously.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't exist

Comment: Now that's anticlimactic. Heh, is this a pro or con of the react useState hook?

Comment: Neither; it's a difference.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response to this question!

Answer (score 2):

There are no 'state' in a function component.

You could have a state object by using 'useReducer' instead. (if your state is a complex object)

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

Comment: Is this considered 'good practice'? Or more of a 'creative solution'?

Comment: @Pgreat Neither; some components require complex state. If you write such a component with aggregated state using hooks, this is what it looks like.

Comment: if your function component need to deal with many state values, you can use the useReducer instead. you need to justify yourself if the component is complex enough. I'd only use it if my component have a complex ui behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting a React App from class based to hooks.

look for something like this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      var1: "foo",
      var2:"bar"
    };
  }
```

in this case
this.state.var1 = **"foo"**
this.state.var2 = **"bar"**
`this.state` =

```
{
      var1: "foo",
      var2:"bar"
}
```